# How can I detect that a overflow has occured in the values of a unsigned long long type

Tags: c, overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to detect integer overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

I have a plain C code which I compile using gcc version 4.4.3 on Ubuntu Linux.

In this code I have a variable of type `unsigned long long int myvar`. Now the code works such that I pass this variable `myvar` to a function `myfunc()` which computes a value for another variable which is also unsigned long long int, and that computed value is mathematically greater than the passed value, and this keeps on happening as the function `myfunc()` is called continuously until some break condition is met.

Now I want to make sure that whenever overflow happens (i.e. the computed value exceeds 9223372036854775807LL which is the `LONG_MAX`), I exit gracefully by displaying the message "Overflow detected" on the console.

1. How Can I detect such overflow? Mostly I would like add any overflow detection code which is portable and does not rely on any standard library/plugin, but makes do with whatever OS available as a part of the language itself.
2. If there is nothing, then  Is there any internal variable set which I can use? or some other non-portable solution?

Any pointers would be useful.

Comment: You cannot reliably detect overflow **after** it has occurred. You need to check if an operation **would** overflow and not do that operation.

Comment: @pmg - That's not entirely true.  Many processors support an [overflow flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overflow_flag) that can be used to check whether or not the previous operation caused an overflow.  Of course, checking it requires assembly code, and would not be portable cross-architecture.

Comment: This question was tagged C. In the C language, you cannot detect overflow after it has occurred. (Also note that in the C language, unsigned value wrapping is not considered "overflow" but a normal part of arithmetic.)